# Spark Streaming + Kafka: Could not compute split, block input ... not found

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

After digging around on Google/SO - I haven't found a good resource on this one yet.

I'm running Spark Streaming 1.2 with the Kafka consumer using Java. When I do larger input tests, about half of my stages fail with:

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 505.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 505.0 (TID 9953, ec2-54-149-87-18.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com): java.lang.Exception: Could not compute split, block input-0-1426033579400 not found
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.BlockRDD.compute(BlockRDD.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.FlatMappedRDD.compute(FlatMappedRDD.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:196)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The pipeline looks like a JavaPairRecieverInputDStream from Kafka, a flatMapToPair call that converts Kafka data into a JavaPairDStream, then a groupByKeyAndWindow to get some batches, then a foreachRDD call that writes batches out to a datastore.

All of the DStreams are set to `.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK())`.

The failures are exclusively in the flatMapToPair calls. For these, the failed stages have wait times ranging from 1-9 minutes in a very (suspiciously?) flat distribution.

I can't find anything about how this data might be getting cleared - am I missing something in the use case here? I could blindly do things to try to make sure all stages are running quickly, but I want to understand the mechanism that is causing this to happen if it is a result of delayed stages.

This question is the same issue, but the publisher isn't lagging behind and so respondents left of the answer. This system is definitely getting backed up, so I think this question occupies a separate space.
[Spark Streaming: Could not compute split, block not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27069740/spark-streaming-could-not-compute-split-block-not-found)

Comment: How is your job's performance? Check the spark ui on the 'streaming' tab for 'total delay'. How long is the streaming batch interval?

Comment: Thanks for the response @massg. I missed something - the processing time and scheduling delay for the jobs are essentially nothing, but a forEachRDD call at the end is blocking everything up. I think my pipeline is getting backed up because the effective processing time is >> than the batch time, and eventually the RDDs are getting collected from memory? I didn't know that they had TTLs.