# Recoverable Kafka WordCount : Could not compute split, block input-0-1449191870000 not found

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

spark RecoverableKafkaWordCount several minutes , when I restart throw this exception:

```
15/12/04 15:27:27 WARN [task-result-getter-0] TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 56, 192.168.0.2): java.lang.Exception: Could not compute split, block input-0-1449191870000 not found
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.BlockRDD.compute(BlockRDD.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: detail problem link=> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27069740/spark-streaming-could-not-compute-split-block-not-found

Answer (score 0):

if we use Recoverable Spark App use this function:

```
 StreamingContext.getOrCreate(PropertyLoader.getValue("spark.checkpoint_directory"), createContext)
```

but I find that `KafkaUtils.createStream` normal `KafkaInputDStream` will will lead to this problem this maybe be a bug, just use `DirectKafkaInputDStream` instead